# how to use s:if tag to match two strings if both strings are field of objects in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I want to compare two strings in jsp page. I am getting one string from java object and other is simple string. I want to know how to compare this string.

**my code**

```
<s:if test="%{Employee.getDesig().equals('Manager') }" >
   <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("You are Manager");
   </script> 
</s:if>
```

The `getDesig()` returns a string.

I have written the above code in a jsp file. Is the above code right or do I have to make any changes ?

Comment: Struts2? Show your action class.

Comment: My action class is bit lengthy.The action class has one method, That method does some processing and returns one string, which is mapped to another jsp page. And in that jsp page I have returned the above code.

Comment: Show what is `Employee.getDesig()` in your action.

Comment: is this java code embedded in jsp? why are you using getters here? Can you please check if you are using the right syntax for struts2?

Comment: It is just returning a String as: public String getDesig(){
        return designation;
    }

Comment: And what is `Employee` then? Try with `employee.desig == 'Manager'`.

Comment: @bgth, Yes this code is written in jsp. I don't know whether getter's are allowed in jsp code or not. You can consider Employee.designation code in that place

Comment: @AleksandrM Employee is a class. It has one designation field which is String. and want to compare this designation field with 'Manager' string

Comment: Do you have getter/setter for `employee` in action?

Comment: @AleksandrM I tried doing designation == 'Manager', but not working

Comment: i think you need to go through online tutorials for struts 2. You will get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you would go about comparing 2 strings, in line with the basic principles of Encapsulation, a **much** better solution would be to add a boolean method to your Employee class:

```
public boolean isManager(){
     return designation.equals("Manager");
}
```

and reference this in your JSP:

```
<s:if test="%{Employee.isManager() }" >
   <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("You are Manager");
   </script> 
</s:if>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)